# Python Connection pymysql

Tags: python-3.x

I'm new in python and I'm facing some issues with my script. I have a def for connection with my db and a model to insert data into it.

This is my connection:

```
def conexao():
    import pymysql

    config = {
        'user': 'root',
        'password': 'admin',
        'host': '127.0.0.1',
        'database': 'megasena'
    }

    try:
        conection = pymysql.connect(**config)
        cursor = conection.cursor()
        return cursor
    except pymysql.InternalError as err:
        if err.errno == errorcode.ER_ACCESS_DENIED_ERROR:
            print('Dados de acessso a Database invalidos!')
        elif err.errno == errorcode.ER_BAD_DB_ERROR:
            print('Database nao existe!')
        else:
            print(err)
```

and in my model I have:

```
import sys
sys.path.append('/home/felipe/Documents/Projetos/MegaSena/conection')
from conn import conexao

class User():

    def insere(self):
        t = conexao()
        t.execute("""INSERT INTO usuarios (nome, email, senha, username) VALUES(
                       "Felipe Paz",
                       "xxfelipepaz@gmail.com",
                       "admin",
                       "felipepaz"
        )""")
```

but it's not working. There's no error message 'cause I can connect with my bd but I cannot insert data or do anything. Does anybody know to tell me what it's wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You should commit to database after executing the query, to save the changes. 
Try adding `connection.commit()` after your insert query.

Also, it would be better if you let us know where are you actually calling the function.